# Error: Notice: Undefined index: select in C:\

Tags: php

My code works properly but an error occurs when I select a value from dropdown (*then error remove.*)

**Error:**

> Notice: Undefined index: select in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\owner_payment.php on line 183

```
<select name="select" id="select" onchange="JavaScript: submit()">
<option value=''>--Select Owner-- </option>
<?php
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) { 
    <option value="<?php echo $row['ownername']; ?>">
      <?php echo $row['ownername'];  ?>
    </option>         
<?php } ?> 
?
</select>
<?php
  $oname=$_POST["select"];//here is error occurr
  if(isset($oname)){
    mysql_select_db("plotscheme", $con);
    $sql1=mysql_query("Select * from payment where name='$oname'")                  
    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($sql1){
        echo $rows['name'].$rows['payment'].$rows['total_payment'].$rows['date'];
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Try checking first `isset($_POST["select"])`

Comment: So the code works properly, but there is an error?

Comment: your code is vulnerable to sql injection

Answer (score 0):

index `select` in your `$_POST` doesn´t exists.

1. Form hasn´t been sent yet: use `isset`
2. Form has been sent, but there is no field with `name=select`